# How to replace this loop (circular list)

Tags: common-lisp

I would like to replace the first few elements of my circular list (1 2 3 4 1 ...) with the same elements in reverse order. I have managed to do it with a loop, but I would like to eliminate it and use a common lisp function which deals with subsequences instead. Can you help me?

```
CL-USER> (setf *print-circle* t)
T
CL-USER> (defvar *cycle*
           (let ((c (list 1 2 3 4)))
             (setf (cdr (last c)) c)))
#1=(1 2 3 4 . #1#)
CL-USER> (let ((reversed-part (list 2 1)))
           (loop for l on *cycle*
              for r in reversed
              do (setf (car l) r))
           *cycle*)
#1=(2 1 3 4 . #1#)
;; Failed attempts:
CL-USER> (let ((reversed-part (list 2 1)))
           (replace *cycle* reversed-part :end1 2 :end2 2)) ;; sets Lisp image spinning forever
CL-USER> (let ((reversed-part (list 2 1)))
           (setf (subseq *cycle* 0 2) reversed-part)) ;; sets Lisp image spinning forever
```

Comment: If you know the size of the replacement at compile time, then [`rotatef`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_rotate.htm) is your friend.

Comment: Thank you, it is a variable. I am still trying to guess what you have in mind, though.

Comment: Notice that circular lists are not proper lists, and thus not sequences or valid inputs to functions that expect a sequence.

Comment: That' today advent of code.

Comment: Actually my question might be misguided, because there is no code to fix the cdr of the previous element to point to the new sequence, but I must note that I have also tried replacing the next elements of the list, eg (replace *cycle* reversed-part :start1 1 :end2 2))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in comments, most functions that work on lists expect *proper* lists. Improper lists like circular ones might lead to infinite loops, or any other bad behavior.

You should better use explicit loops.

However, mapping functions like `mapcar`, `maplist`, ... must work with lists of different sizes (they end when the shortest one ends), so as long as one of the arguments is proper, you can generally expect the mapping to end (there is however still no guarantee). Likewise, `subseq` is likely to terminate if `:end` is provided:

```
;; IMPORTANT
(setf *print-circle* t)

(defun nrevplace (list start end)
  (mapl (lambda (u v) (setf (car u) (car v)))
        (nthcdr start list)
        (nreverse (subseq list start end))))

(let ((list (list 1 2 3 :a :b :c 4)))
  (setf list (nconc list list))
  (nrevplace list 3 6)
  list)

#1=(1 2 3 :C :B :A 4 . #1#)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps you could add (setf \*print-circle\* t) at the top, in case someone (like e.g. me!) forgets to do it and runs the code directly.